# How to get jQuery object value?

Tags: php, jquery

This is my console response and I want to get the value of preObject:

```
jQuery.fn.init(4) [ "val2", "val31", "val1", "val1", prevObject: 
jQuery.fn.init(4), context: document]0: "val2"1: "val31"2: "val1"3:
"val1"context: documentlength: 4prevObject:
jQuery.fn.init(4) ["dropdown1", "dropdown2", "dropdown3", "dropdown4",
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(4), context: document]__proto__: Object(0)
```

I have used the following to get val2, val31, val1 but I didn't get dropdown1,2,3.

How to get that?

Comment: Please fix the formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Show some html and js codes